# Java Rest API secured by Azure AD

Tags: java, rest, azure

I've an angular app which calls a java rest api to get the data. We need to secure these apps by azure AD.

I'm using ADAL.js library for angular app and trying to find any library which can be used for rest api but haven't found any on the internet. All the samples are provided for webAPi which is using Microsoft's OWIN framework.

Currently my understanding is that,  our angular app will call to Azure AD to get the access token and will send that to java rest api. 
Its a JWT token signed by RSA private key. 
I can get the public key from JWKs uri and validate whether the JWT token and its signature is valid or not. If it's valid, the rest api will send the response back to angular app
 -  Is it enough on rest api side? Don't we need any communication between Rest api and Azure AD ? What if someone steals the access token and use that (within its expiration period ?) 
I was under impression that resource server ( java rest api) also needs to talk to Authorization server (Azure AD) but not sure if it's really required for JWT tokens.

Comment: Could you host your Java REST service on Azure Web App? Or you host these two app on the Azure web app?

Answer (score 0):

@Deb,I found your reqirement matched this scenarios----Web application to Web API.I recommend you refer to this document(
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#web-application-to-web-api). If your front-end used the Angular App, you could use passportjs to pass Azure AD authorization. Please refer to documnet( 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-nodejs/#6-install-passportjs-in-to-your-web-api).

> Its a JWT token signed by RSA private key. I can get the public key
>   from JWKs uri and validate whether the JWT token and its signature is
>   valid or not. If it's valid, the rest api will send the response back
>   to angular app - Is it enough on rest api side? Don't we need any
>   communication between Rest api and Azure AD ?

If you got the access_token,you could call your REST API with this token in your request.  You need not any communication between REST API and AAD. But please note, you need make your API application trust another application

> What if someone steals the access token and use that (within its
>   expiration period ?) I was under impression that resource server (
>   java rest api) also needs to talk to Authorization server (Azure AD)
>   but not sure if it's really required for JWT tokens.

You also can set the expiration time in your application for the tokens. See the part 'Token Expiration' in this document(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#application-types-and-scenarios)